# Is there a more efficient way in processing an integer datatype?

Tags: types, pattern-matching, sml

I have the following piece of code:

```
datatype eInt = infinity of int | 0 | Int of int;

exception undefined;
fun eAdd(e1:eInt, 0:eInt) = e1
  | eAdd(0, e2) = e2
  | eAdd(e1, infinity) = infinity
  | eAdd(infinity, e1) = infinity
  | eAdd(infinity, ~infinity) = raise undefined
  | eAdd(~infinity, infinity) = raise undefined
  | eAdd(e1, e2) = e1 + e2;
```

There's a new datatype which allows for three types: infinity, 0, and int. I think 0 may be redundant here but I'm not all sure.

I used pattern matching to formulate the different types of possible results from adding the two eInts together.

---

There are four different outcomes.

- If there's a 0, return other int
- If there's a ∞ , return ∞
- If there's a ∞ and -∞ , return undefined
- Anything else, return the addition of the two of them

---

The only thing I can think of which makes this algorithm more efficient is if I were to remove the double cases, and at the end, run the algorithm again after reversing (e1, e2) to (e2, e1).

Any ideas on making this more efficient? I will be adding other operations such as division, which will have even more cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `0` is redundant, since you also have `Int 0`.
2. Use uppercase constructor names.
3. You have not really said what you mean by `Infinity of int`. Judging from your examples, you are only interested in whether the infinity is positive or negative, so an *int* is quite redundant, too.
4. Instead of using exceptions, use an *option* type.

In summary, you might have

```
datatype IntExt = PosInf
                | NegInf
                | Int of int

fun extAdd (PosInf, i2) = if i2 = NegInf then NONE else SOME PosInf
  | extAdd (i1, PosInf) = if i1 = NegInf then NONE else SOME PosInf
  | extAdd (NegInf, _) = SOME NegInf
  | extAdd (_, NegInf) = SOME NegInf
  | extAdd (Int a, Int b) = SOME (Int (a+b))
```

If you want an efficient implementation, consider encoding your integers as [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: Hi Simon, just wanted to say thank you overall. You're helping me out a lot and I really appreciate what you're doing. I have, since posting it, revised my answer. I've made most of the changes you have, except there are some more changes. I'll modify my question so others can see what I have now. The only difference is, can I ask what `NONE` and `SOME` do in this scenario?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh: Comments on StackOverflow aren't really suitable for forth-and-back discussion. I recommend that you read the appropriate section of an introductory book like [H&R](http://www.it.dtu.dk/introSML/). Or you can google around: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980801/what-are-the-options-some-and-none-sml), [here](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/10-ml-exceptions.html) (last resource seems quite fine).

Answer (score 1):

- I removed the "recursion" tag, since there's no recursion in this function.
- If you're particularly worried about efficiency, order the clauses from most to least frequent.  This likely means that your "undefined" clauses would go last.
- Check on the relative efficiency of choosing a clause.  It's possible that taking the time to evaluate the arguments and switch half the time, will consume any savings from shorter code.

Comment: Thanks, I added the tag pattern-matching, sorry about the wrong tag. Wouldn't moving the undefined down mean `eAdd(e1, e2)` will always be evaluated instead? I'll try though. As for the third point, that sounds right. Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Oh.  Duh.  Yes, leave the default clause for last.  OOPS!  :-)